# How to combine ARKit and SwiftUI without using the storyboard and/or IBOutlets?

Tags: ios, arkit, swiftui

I just started making apps for iOS. When I want to create an ARView using SwiftUI and without the Storyboard, that is all going well. However, when I change the ARView to SKView or ARSCNView, it does not work (it results in a grey screen). In all the examples that I find on the internet, this requires an IBOutlet to the StoryBoard.

Is there a way to work around this IBOutlets/storyboard? I would prefer to not use the storyboard, if possible.

```
struct ARViewContainer: UIViewRepresentable {

func makeUIView(context: Context) -> SKView {

    let arView = SKView(frame: .zero) //ARView(frame: .zero)

    return arView

}

func updateUIView(_ uiView: SKView, context: Context) {}

}
```

(Code above results in a grey screen in the app)

Answer (score 0):

It could be because you're missing the code necessary to present the scene:

```
let scene: SKScene

func updateUIView(_ uiView: SKView, context: Context) {
    uiView.presentScene(scene)
}
```

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/spritekit/skview/1519705-presentscene

Answer (score 0):

You have to return a **ARSCNView** instead of an SKView.

Also, you just have to configure the session for ARWorldTrackingConfiguration and run it:

```
import SwiftUI
import ARKit

struct MyARScnView: UIViewRepresentable {
            
    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> ARSCNView {
            
        let arView = ARSCNView(frame: .zero)
            
        // Create a session configuration
        let configuration = ARWorldTrackingConfiguration()
            
        // Run the view's session
        arView.session.run(configuration)
            
        return arView
    }
        
    func updateUIView(_ uiView: ARSCNView, context: Context) {
        
    }
}
```